# Java : Comparing two ArrayLists, remove values, which are not matching

Tags: java, arraylist

I need your help :

I have a certain object, containing values. Some of these values are equal and some differs.
Based on same values i need two compare two ArrayLists of these objects. At least I have to remove all entries which aren't stored in both lists.

I wrote a function, which compares the certain fields in the certain Object :

```
public void compareTwoValues(certainObj1, certainObj2){
    boolean returnStmt = true;
    for(int i : keysToCheck){
    if(!(jop1.returnValueForKey(i).equals(jop2.returnValueForKey(i)))){
            returnStmt = false;
        }
    }
    return returnStmt;
}
```

Now i have the problem, how to access and remove objects, where the function returns false ?

I tried to sort them with the help of the comparable interface and to remove values, but I got always a 'concurrentmodificationexception' (yeah, i know : i used the the iterator-loop).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you provide required out put, for an input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArrayList has boolean retainAll(Collection another) which retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the specified collection. To make it work in your situation you could create a wrapper over original object with equals method which compares only required fields and place the wrappers in the ArrayList.

Comment: It's not working as requested. If first list f is { "a", "b", "c" } and second s is { "a", "b" }, than calling f.retailnAll( s ) removes nothing from f, but "c" have to be removed...

Comment: I tested it, l1.retainAll(l2); and got [a, b]

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean with wrapper to compare the certain values ... ?

Comment: a class which holds a ref to YourClass object and implements equals which does what compareTwoValues does. Then instead of adding objects to the list you add wrappers - list1.add(new Wrapper(obj)). Now lists contain Wrappers, when you list1.retainAll(list2) ArrayList will call equals on wrappers and wrappers will compare wrapped objects

Comment: sorry, i still don't get it. i overrided the 'equals' function within my 'certainclass' and cast the argument to my certain class. In the debugger i can see, that the program is using my function, but the retainAll function doesn't change any list ...

Comment: go step by step. make your Weapper.equals return true always. then list1.retainAll(list2) should kill all wrappers in list1. if this works then your equals is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Java Apache common library provides subtraction functionality. You can use listutils class to subtract values between two lists.

Please refer this below link
[How does ListUtils.subtract() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073120/how-does-listutils-subtract-work)

Comment: this was my first approach, but some values within the objects are not equal.

Comment: If you override object's equal method, you can get right output

Comment: okay, i didn't know - i will try this ! thanks a lot, i will give you feedback !

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this one.

```
public class ProductComparator implements Comparator<Product>
{
      public int compare(Product p1, Product p2)
      {
           // do your comparison here
           return p1.id-p2.id;
      }
}


ArrayList<Product> listProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
listProducts.add(new Product(5, "Soda", 1.00, 1));
listProducts.add(new Product(3,"Phone", 300.00, 2));
listProducts.add(new Product(4, "Cofee", 5.00, 3));
listProducts.add(new Product(5, "Soda", 1.00, 4));
listProducts.add(new Product(4, "Cofee", 5.00, 5));
listProducts.add(new Product(5, "Soda", 1.00, 6));
System.out.println(listProducts.size()); // Total records 

TreeSet<Product> products = new TreeSet<Product>(new ProductComparator());
products.addAll(listProducts);                
ArrayList<Product> duplicate = new ArrayList<Product>();
duplicate.addAll(products);
listProducts.removeAll(duplicate);
System.out.println(products.size()); // Now no duplicates in this set. 
System.out.println(listProducts.size()); // Now only duplicate in this list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) in order to do that quick and easily. Just build your predicate and filter elements that match.

Some examples here -> http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/1591

Answer (score 0):

A ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when a collection changes in a manner which invalidates open iterators. This usually happens when a collection which is not thread safe is accessed by multiple threads.

You can use either `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` or make a copy (or get an array with Collection.toArray method) before iterating the list in the thread.

Besides that, removing in a for-each construction breaks iterator, so it's not a valid way to process the list in this case.